# Binary File IOException

Tags: java, binaryfiles, ioexception

So, I've been have issues with a homework assignment for about three weeks now, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have to write a program that will search a binary file of numbers of type int and have the program write them from smallest to largest. The file cannot contain anything but numbers of type int.

Here's my program:

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.EOFException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class BinaryFile
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
        int[] numArray = new int[10];
        try 
        {
          DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("numbers.dat")); //creates an object that reads from numbers.dat
          System.out.println("Reading the integers from numbers.dat");
          int i;
          for(i = 0;i < 10;i++) //takes the numbers from number.dat and puts them in numArray
          {
            numArray[i] = inputStream.readInt();
          }
          inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(EOFException e)
        {
          System.out.println("End of file reached");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
          System.out.println("numbes.dat not found");
          System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
          System.out.println("IOException found");
          e.printStackTrace;
          System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("Other exception found.");
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Re-ordering numbers.");
        Arrays.sort(numArray); //reorders the numbers in the array
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) //prints out the numbers in the array
        {
          System.out.println(numArray[j]);
        }
      }
    }
```

The output is as follows:

```
    Reading the integers from numbers.dat
    End of file reached
    java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at BinaryFile.main(BinaryFile.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
        at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
        at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
        at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
        at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:246)
        at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:220)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/15621596.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Re-ordering numbers.
    0
    0
    0
    0
    540090425
    540483633
    807416628
    825368627
    891304224
    941634610
```

Basically, its refusing to read in the numbers from the numbers.dat. I'm not really sure what the problem is.

The numbers I'm using in numbers.dat are:
5 9 12 3 7 10 34 1 98 42

Comment: What is the stacktrace and message of the `IOException`?

Comment: in `catch(...)` put `e.printStackTrace()` so you can see the error your getting.

Comment: How did you *write* this file? And when you get an exception, don't display some useless message of your own devising. Display the one that comes with the exception. Display the whole exception. The whole stack trace. There's quite enough information there to solve most problems.

Comment: I updated it. Sorry about that. I'm still new to the site, and I'm also still learning to program.

Comment: That error message says that the stream header (used to identify the file type of binary files) is corrupted. Maybe it is not a serialized binary file.

Comment: Please don't *replace* your question with the "solution". If you want to add a solution, do so at the bottom, below your original question. Otherwise you're not being fair to the people who made an effort to answer your question, because - since they question is gone - they now look weird, and you're not being fair to the purpose of StackOverflow - being a knowledge base of useful questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So an Object input stream is not really what you want.

You would do better with a DataInputStream.

```
DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("numbers.dat"));
```

Comment: To expand on that, and what @sri-harsha-chilakapati said, ObjectInputStream is for reading a specific data format, a serialized binary file. You don't have that. DataInputStream is specifically for the application you require.

Comment: I changed it, so that definitely fixed one of the problems! Thanks :) However, it seems like there's another problem...

Comment: @RaychilPostlethwait What is that problem, specifically

Comment: Its not reading the numbers from numbers.dat correctly. If I use the same small numbers that I listed in the post, then it reads it as five vastly different numbers. If I change them to integers in the thousands, then it reads it as ten numbers, but not the same numbers I have in numbers.dat.

Comment: @RaychilPostlethwait, I am looking at the numbers you are getting in your array. They are obviously not the ten integers that are supposed to be in the file. But what I see is, when you convert those numbers into bytes, they are the text strings of the digits. So I have to ask, how was the file written, how did you make numbers.dat

Comment: I wrote it using notepad, then saved it as a .dat. That's how my teacher told me to do it >.>

Comment: @RaychilPostlethwait It looks like you typed the literal numbers in a text editor into the file. That will not work. That is a text file, not a binary file. You can write a binary file the same way you read it, except using DataOutputStream and the method writeInt().

Comment: @RaychilPostlethwait Are you certain that your teacher told you that the file was a binary file and not a text file, because you can't create a binary file that way.

Comment: ...Wow, I see exactly were I'm going wrong. Thanks for helping talk through all this :)

Answer (score 0):

to parse the file use scanner.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryFile
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Integer[] numArray = new Integer[10];
    try 
    {
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new File("D:/abc.dat")); //creates an object that reads from numbers.dat
      System.out.println("Reading the integers from numbers.dat");
      int i;
      for(i = 0;i < 10;i++) //takes the numbers from number.dat and puts them in numArray
      {
        numArray[i] = inputStream.nextInt();
      }
      inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      System.out.println("numbes.dat not found");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println("IOException found");
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Other exception found.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Re-ordering numbers.");
    Arrays.sort(numArray); //reorders the numbers in the array
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) //prints out the numbers in the array
    {
      System.out.println(numArray[j]);
    }
  }
}
```